# How do I compare and decrypt md5 password hashes in C?

Tags: c, encryption, hash, cryptography, md5

This program is for comparing password hashes. I am getting it to say `Reading (filename)`, but then I get a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. I believe something is wrong in my main or readfile function. Is fscanf causing the problem here? And what is the middle argument in the for loop in main, i believe it would be number of lines, correct? I hav eprovided comments for better direction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "crypt.h"

int tryguess(char *hash, char *guess)
{
    // Extract the salt from the hash
    char *salt;
    memcpy(salt, &hash[3], 8);
    salt[8] = '\0'; 
    // Hash the guess using the salt
    char *hashGuess = md5crypt(guess, salt);
    // Compare the two hashes
    if (strcmp(hashGuess, hash) == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

// Given a hash and a dictionary of guesses,
// try all guesses and return the matching guess.
char *crack(char *hash, char *dict[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (dict[i])
    {
        if (tryguess(hash, dict[i])) return dict[i];
        i++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

// Read in a file.
// The first line of the file is the number of lines in the file.
// Returns an array of strings, with the last element being a NULL
// indicating the end of the array.
char **read_file(char *fname)
{
    char **dict;

    printf("Reading %s\n", fname);

    FILE *d = fopen(fname, "r");

    if (! d) return NULL;
    // Get the number of lines in the file
    char *size;
    fscanf(d, "%s[^\n]", size);
    int filesize = atoi(size); 

    // Allocate memory for the array of strings (character pointers)
    dict[0] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char *));

    // Read in the rest of the file, allocting memory for each string
    // as we go.
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (count < filesize)
    {
        for (int i = 0; dict[i] != NULL; i++)
        {
            fscanf(d, "%s[^\n]\n", dict[i]);
            if (dict[i+1] != NULL)
            {
                dict[i+1] = malloc(1000);
            }
            count++;
            index++;
        }
    }


    // NULL termination. Last entry in the array should be NULL.
    dict[index] = NULL;

    printf("Done\n");
    fclose(d);
    return dict;
  }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) 
    {
        printf("Usage: %s hash_file dict_file\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    char **dictionary = read_file(argv[2]);
    char **hashes = read_file(argv[1]);

    // For each hash, try every entry in the dictionary.
    // Print the matching dictionary entry.
    for (int i = 0; i < (# of lines); i++)
    {
    char *hash = hashes[i];
    char *result = crack(hash, dictionary);
    printf("%s", result);
    }   
}
```

Comment: md5 is a hash. it cannot be "decrypted". You're asking to make a cow out of hamburger. md5 is the meat grinder.

Comment: If you want to decrypt it, you should check a rainbow table, because MD5 can not be decrypted.

Comment: changed, is it better?

Comment: @MarcB True, but of course if you want to reproduce a particular hamburger, it may be viable to breed & grind many different cows until you find one that results in a hamburger identical to your target hamburger. This is what OP intended considering the code, so your only point is one of terminology.

Comment: You can't decrypt it, what can you do is find string which returns you same `MD5` hash code (brute force). Here are some useful informations: [Are there two known strings which have the same MD5 hash value?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value)

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see is this (which can be causing segmentation fault):

```
// Extract the salt from the hash
char *salt;
memcpy(salt, &hash[3], 8);
salt[8] = '\0';
```

You can't write anything to `salt`, because it is just pointer,
no memory allocation has been done.
You can declare it on stack, if you know it's max size for instance, e.g., `char salt[16];`.
Usage is also similar: `memcpy(salt, &hash[3], 8);`

Comment: changed to salt[9], but still same error unfortunatley

Answer (score 1):

The segmentation fault (core dumped) is an error you get when:

> By addressing non-existent/allocated memory.

Trying to read from an illegal memory location will cause this fault. i.e.

1. If you fopen a file, it fails and the file pointer returned is NULL and you try to read from that file pointer. This will give you a segmentation fault.

Comment: I'm getting it to read the first file, as you see in main, with dictionary, but the second one returns a segment error, even though the file exists

Answer (score 0):

```
    dict[i] = string;
    dict = malloc(1000);
```

In what world do these two lines make sense together?  You set a pointer (to a stack allocated string!) then you ignore your prior buffer, `dict`, in favor of a new one.  These pointer errors need fixed!

Comment: could i just do dict[i+1] = malloc(1000)?

Comment: That change alone is not sufficient.  Notice how you are completely  ignoring the current value of `dict[i]` when setting `dict[i] = string;`.  Stop with the stack-allocated string, allocate your dictionary entries properly and place your values directly in the dictionary.  Also, how do you know 1000 bytes is enough?

Comment: ok, i edited post, to the way I think you were saying. still segment error though =/